# $5^a - a^2 \geq 5^{a-1}$ for $a \geq 12$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation

How do I show that $5^a - a^2 \geq 5^{a-1}$ for $a \geq 12$ where $a \in \mathbb{N}$? I'm trying to use this inequality as a part of larger proof but every time I read this statement while going through my proof, this jump seems a bit too abrupt(although I know it is true and can easily be checked via a calculator). I would be very grateful if someone could show me the steps in between and what I am missing in particular as this would also be teaching me what to do in the future when I encounter such a situation.

Comment: By the way, this **can't** be checked by calculator. It can be checked for any **given** $a \geq 7$ by calculator, sure, but just computing a few examples which support this hypothesis is not enough. To prove that it is true for **all** $a \geq 7$, you have to use some elementary algebra/calculus/proof by induction.

Comment: I agree that I haven't been able to prove it but you can gain intuition to point you in the right direction via a calculator, and then, for less obvious proofs, say use induction.

Comment: Yes, and this is a less obvious proof. All three of the answers here tell you to use induction. It's a very easy induction as well. If for some reason you don't want to use induction, then you should explicitly state that in your question. But really induction is the way to go here.

Comment: Why have you edited your question in this way rather than just ask a new question? The logic remains the same: this is **not** an obvious one-liner where you can just write $5^a - a^2 \geq \ldots \geq 5^{a-1}$. We're talking about the difference between an exponential and a square on one side and an exponential on the other, and there's no obvious chain of inequalities. The easiest justification is to take the exponentials to one side (factorising the difference as $5^a - 5^{a-1} = 4 \cdot 5^{a-1}$) and the square to the other and prove that inequality via induction, starting from $a=12$.

Answer (score 0):

We need to show that $2^a\geq2a^2$.

Indeed, for $a=7$ we obtain $128\geq98,$ which is true.

We'll prove that $$2^a\geq2a^2\Rightarrow2^{a+1}\geq2(a+1)^2.$$
Indeed, $$2^{a+1}\geq4a^2.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$4a^2\geq2(a+1)^2$$ or
$$a^2-2a-1\geq0,$$ which is true for $a\geq7$ and we are done by induction.

Answer (score -1):

Rearrange to get $2^{a-1} \geq a^2$ for $a \geq 7$, then it's pretty easy to prove by induction.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question. I'm not asking for re-arranging to something simpler and then work backwards to my result(what I want to show). I'm asking how to get from the left side of the inequality I posted to the right.

Comment: @YFP I've literally answered the question you posed: "How do I show that $2^a - a^2  \geq 2^{a-1}$ for $a \geq 7$?". You can't just immediately see that this inequality should hold without a little reasoning, and this is precisely what I gave. It's pretty straightforward reasoning: after rearranging, it becomes clearer that the left-hand side grows faster than the right, and the first time the left-hand side is bigger is for $a = 7$. If you are going to downvote valid answers because you don't understand how basic proof techniques work, I suggest you stop using Stack Exchange.